# Umlaute not working anymore after Upgrade to 20.04

Tags: keyboard-layout, 20.04

I usually use `alt`+`u` and then `a` to get `ä` on my English(Macintosh) keyboard. I upgraded to 20.04 this morning. This key combo now gives me the letter `ă`. Same goes for `ŭ`.

The function "Show Keyboard Layout" still shows me the old combo though.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? The reason I chose the mac layout is because it allows me to type umlauts and still be productive with semicolons , brackets and stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow you have defined your <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key as the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). To go back to the original behavior:

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package (if not installed already)
- Open *Tweaks* and select *Keyboard & Mouse*
- Open the *Compose Key* menu and disable it (or define some other key but <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as the compose key)

Comment: You are awesome, thank you. Interestingly it was already defined as Right Alt, but disabling it fixed the issue.